# how do I use the fourier series formula to find the fourier series for this function?$f(x)=\frac12(\pi-x), 0 \lt x \lt 2\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Find the fourier series representation of 
$$f(x)=\frac12(\pi-x), 0 \lt x \lt 2\pi$$
to calculate $a_0, a_n \text{ and } b_n$ I have to use the integrals $\int_{-L}^L$ but is $-L=0 \text{ and } L=2\pi \text{  or is } -L=-\pi \text{ and } L=\pi$ for this problem? I think the period is $2\pi$ I am not sure if I use the bounds of the interval as the bounds of the integral or the fact that the period should be 2L?

Comment: yes it is a similar question but can you just explain why they introduced g(x) by splitting f(x) into two functions? because I stilll don't understand where they got the bounds for the integrals of $a_n$ and $b_n$?

Comment: Do not think of the function $f$ as defined on just $[0,2\pi]$.  It should be thought of as defined everywhere so as to be $2\pi$-periodic.  Then you can compute the Fourier coefficients by integrating on *any* interval of length $2\pi$.  It is a lot easier to integrate on $[-\pi,\pi]$ than on  $[0,2\pi]$.  But to do so you will have to figure out what the values of the function would have to be on that interval.  We already know the values on $[0,\pi]$ so just try to determine the values on $[-\pi,0]$.  That is where the "split" function $g$ in the other answer comes in.

Comment: i did found the fourier series twice, once with the bound $[-\pi, \pi]$ with two functions $g(x)$ and then I did it with the bounds $[0, 2\pi]$ and it was so much quicker to do it without splitting it into two function because you have half the number of ingrals to solve and plugging in $0$ and $2\pi$ after integrating was very simple. splitting the function so you can sole it over $[-\pi, \pi]$ makes the problem twice as long.

Comment: Some people find it easier to use the fact the function is odd and then just integrate over $[0,\pi]$ to get a sin series.  But the point of the exercise was just to figure what it all meant and you have succeeded.  Nobody really has much fun computing Fourier coefficients--the theory is fun though.